# How to join two tables together to get the following result in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, left-join, right-join

I have two tables, table 1 has only 1 column like this:

```
Identifier
   A
   B
   C
   D
```

The second table has two columns like this:

```
Identifier        CCC 
    A             10
    C             20
```

I need to join these two tables together like this one:

```
Identifier     CCC
    A          10 
    B          
    C          20
    D
```

Comment: Left join on table1.identifier =table2.identifier

Comment: I can tell you SQL syntax or query not familiar with MySQL

Answer (score 3):

This is a classic use case for a `left join`, that will just leave `null`s where the joined table doesn't have a matching record:

```
SELECT    t1.identifier, t2.ccc
FROM      t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.identifier = t2.identifier
```